# How do you coerce shiny select inputs to be numbers to calculate average score?

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, reactive-programming, reactive

I have a shiny app where users can select different options ("", very low, low, medium, high), and I want to give users an average score based on their selections within each section as well as an overall average (with very low = 1, low = 2, etc--the blank option should be treated as NA). I know if I were doing this in a normal, non-reactive dataset, I could use dplyr's `case_when()`, but I'm not sure how to do it for each input. Though I'm open to any solution, I'd appreciate one that uses tidy functions, especially case_when().

The actual survey has 30 questions, so I'd prefer not to call out each input individually if possible (they all start with a similar stem, like the below example). Last, each average should be a number (not a character string), so I can do other computations later.

Appreciate any help! Below is a reproducible example to demonstrate:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
    title = "Personalized Quiz",
    useShinyjs(),
    useShinydashboard(),
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Quiz",
                 sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                         h2("Section 1"),
                         selectInput("q1", "Question 1",
                                     choices = c("", "Very Low", "Low",
                                                 "Medium", "High")),
                         selectInput("q2", "Question 2",
                                     choices = c("", "Very Low", "Low",
                                                 "Medium", "High")),
                         h2("Section 2"),
                         selectInput("q3", "Question 3",
                                     choices = c("", "Very Low", "Low",
                                                 "Medium", "High")),
                         selectInput("q4", "Question 4",
                                     choices = c("", "Very Low", "Low",
                                                 "Medium", "High"))
                     ),
                     mainPanel(textOutput("section1_results"),
                               textOutput("section2_results"),
                               textOutput("overall_results"))

    ))))


server <- function(input, output) {
    
    section_1 <- reactive({
                        #create section_1 average here

    })
    
    section_2 <- reactive({
                #create section_2 average here

    })
    
    overall <- reactive({
        #create overall average here
    })
    
    output$section1_results <- renderText(paste0("Your section 1 average is ", section_1, "."))
    output$section2_results <- renderText(paste0("Your section 2 average is ", section_2, "."))
    output$overall_results <- renderText(paste0("Your overall average is ", overall, "."))
    

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: @RonakShah, apologies! I edited the code to load the library(shinyWidgets) which has that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to solve your issue; In the selectInputs you can assign hidden values to choices like shown in the code. Also make sure that in the outputs you refer to your reactives in the correct way, meaning you include empty brackets at the end.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Personalized Quiz",
  useShinyjs(),
  useShinydashboard(),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Quiz",
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 h2("Section 1"),
                 selectInput("q1", "Question 1",
                             choices = c("", "Very Low" = 1, "Low" = 2,
                                         "Medium" = 3, "High" = 4)),
                 selectInput("q2", "Question 2",
                             choices = c("", "Very Low" = 1, "Low" = 2,
                                         "Medium" = 3, "High" = 4)),
                 h2("Section 2"),
                 selectInput("q3", "Question 3",
                             choices = c("", "Very Low" = 1, "Low" = 2,
                                         "Medium" = 3, "High" = 4)),
                 selectInput("q4", "Question 4",
                             choices = c("", "Very Low" = 1, "Low" = 2,
                                         "Medium" = 3, "High" = 4)),
               ),
               mainPanel(textOutput("section1_results"),
                         textOutput("section2_results"),
                         textOutput("overall_results"))
               
             ))))


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  section_1 <- reactive({
    #create section_1 average here
    mean(c(as.numeric(input$q1), as.numeric(input$q2)), na.rm = T)
  })
  
  section_2 <- reactive({
    #create section_2 average here
    mean(c(as.numeric(input$q3), as.numeric(input$q4)), na.rm = T)
  })
  
  overall <- reactive({
    #create overall average here
    mean(c(as.numeric(input$q1), as.numeric(input$q2), as.numeric(input$q3), as.numeric(input$q4)), na.rm = T)
  })
  
  output$section1_results <- renderText(paste0("Your section 1 average is ", section_1(), "."))
  output$section2_results <- renderText(paste0("Your section 2 average is ", section_2(), "."))
  output$overall_results <- renderText(paste0("Your overall average is ", overall(), "."))
  
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: this is great! One question, is there anyway to use %in% or dplyr's starts_with() when doing this for overall other than copy and paste (e.g., starts_with("q")? I'm not sure how or if that could work.